# Firebase OrderByChild() and EqualTo() is not working properly

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I need to find the existing Child inside the Random Key and I have used OrderByChild() and EqualTo() to filter the queries but it behaves soo weird that for sometimes it showing child exists for only one Child and for sometimes it doesnot work.

[image: Firebase Structure]

i need to check for the child (date_expense) of "February_2019" exist or not? i've tried this

**MainActivity**

```
databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Expenses_Details");
        expensesaddref = databaseReference.child(username).child("Expense_Month").child(monthyr); 
 int currentInt=Integer.parseInt(currentdate); 
        numberToWord((currentInt % 100));
        Log.d("date_string",String.valueOf(dateString)); 
        final String date_expense=expensesname +"" + dateString;
final ExpenseClass expenses=new ExpenseClass(expensesname,currentdate,date_expense,totalcost);

        expensesaddref.orderByChild("date_expense").equalTo(date_expense).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Expense Already exists!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else {
                            String key = expensesaddref.push().getKey();
                            expensesaddref.child(key).setValue(expenses);
                            showListAdd(expensesname);
                            Log.d("Adding", "Data Adding");
                        }





            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        }}
```

**Note**

if child exist already in db then it should display toast but expense is again adding even though the child is already db

In the Program,

`monthYr` is February_2019

`Currentdate` is date of the present day

`dateString` is date in words(ie one,Eleven,Twenty)

This is the Firebase structure what Iam getting .`date_expense` is adding even though child is exist already
[image]

Comment: What happens when you run that code in a debugger? Does the `onDataChange` get triggered? If so, what is `dataSnapshot.exists()`?

Comment: Also note that if you're sure all the values of variables are correct, you should also be able to reproduce the problem with a hard-coded path. That would help rule out any of the variables being the cause of the problem.

Comment: Ya `onDatachange`  its triggering ..if child exist already in db then it should display toast but expense is again adding even though the child is already db @Frank van Puffelen

Comment: For checking purpose i have executed this line `expensesaddref.orderByChild("expensesName").equalTo(expensename)` it works fine but `expensesaddref.orderByChild("date_expense").equalTo(date_expense)` is not working

Comment: So that sounds like `date_expense` doesn't have the right value. Can you reproduce the proble with a hard-coded value for `date_expense`?

Comment: Ya for sure i will try but now I am out of home.i will try and let you know

Comment: I have tried Hardcoded value for `date_expense` but still it doesnot work.I have attached firebase structure what iam getting?

Comment: thanks for your time in solving my problem. I have attached code which is working fine @Frank van Pufflen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found that the below code working as per my need

```
ValueEventListener valueEventListener=new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                boolean isTitleAlreadyUsed = false;

                for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    if (ds.hasChild("date_expense") && (expDate.equals(ds.child("date_expense").getValue()))) {
                        isTitleAlreadyUsed = true;
                    }
                }
                if(isTitleAlreadyUsed){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Exist",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else
                {
                    String key=expensesaddref.push().getKey();
                    expensesaddref.child(key).setValue(expenseClass);
                    showListAdd(lower_exp);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        expensesaddref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```